# Download zip file, extract and overwrite windows 2008 r2

Tags: windows, powershell, download, extract

I have been looking for a way to download a zip file from a URL, have it extracted to a destination folder and then overwrite any files which are the same. I looked at powershell scripts but could not get one to work.

Working on a windows 2008 r2 server. Any insights would be great on the most efficent, easiest way to achieve this

cheers

Comment: Can you include what you've been able to do so far? I don't know a command to extract .zip files with the windows shell but you might want to use some other software such as 7-zip that have a command-line executable. As for overwriting files, copy commands will do that if you give them (the `/Y` option)

Answer (score 2):

If you download and install `7Zip` form [here](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html), then use the following `PowerShell` command that uses the `7z.exe` file. You will be able to unzip and overwrite files to a given location.

```
$ZipFile = "T:\file1.zip"
$zipToFolder = "C:\UnzipToThisFolder\"
& "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" x $ZipFile -o"$zipToFolder" -y
```

Parameters:

```
x: extract files with full paths
-o{Directory}: set Output directory
-y: assume Yes on all queries (Overwrites)
```

If the zip file you want to unzip is on a website you will need to download the file first and then unzip it. You can download files from a website in `PowerShell` like this:

```
$source = "http://www.site.co.uk/something/Yourfile.zip"
$destination = "C:\DownloadTo\Folder\fileNAme.zip"

Invoke-WebRequest $source -OutFile $destination
```

Comment: Hi Chard, Does $ZipFile allow to use url e.g google.com/file.zip